# MediaPlayer makes Android app crashes

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I'm making it so a button makes sound when clicked and I keep running into an error. heres my java code:

```
package com.thisisfoo.testgame;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;


 public class Main extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer buttonSound;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


 //Button sounds
    final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.test);

 //setting up buttons
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            buttonSound.start();
            startActivity(new Intent("com.thisisfoo.testgame"));
        }
    });
}
```

It plays the sound when I run it, but it crashes and says "unfortunately, TEST has stopped". Can anyone help me please. Thanks!

edit:
heres my logcat

```
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.thisisfoo.testgame }
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1638)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1510)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3263)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3370)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at com.thisisfoo.testgame.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:35)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14319)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5060)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 02-02 22:56:29.401: E/AndroidRuntime(27328):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your logcat should have a stack trace.  Post it.  My guess is that it can't find that activity com.thisisfoo.testgame-  either you don't have it in your manifest or you don't have it at all.

Comment: post AndroidManifest xml also

Comment: Hmm.. I feel it's more likely to be some problem with the "startActivity" part rather than buttonSound.start()

Answer (score 0):

as in log:

> ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

because you are not passing right action to start next activity. try to start next Activity as :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this,Your_Next_Activity.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This crash is because of your media player is playing sound in main activity context while you start another activity. you can solve this by different way e.g 
either you start this media playerin thread or wait for your media player to stop and then start another activity